# Perform (brief) animation when app switches into background

Tags: ios, ios8, core-animation

Can I start a (brief) animation when the user has pressed the home buttom and my app is therefore sent into the background?

It is basically about moving a progress indicator back to its default position (because switching away from the app cancels progress in the app's context) in a "nice" way.

Starting it in a notification handler for `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` is apparently too late, for the UI is now longer shown.